Uniformizers in one-dimensional local rings
Suppose that $R$ is a Noetherian ring with unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Further suppose that $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is a one-dimensional $R/\mathfrak{m}$-vector space. By an application of a corollary of Nakayama's lemma (see here) we can infer that $\mathfrak{m}=\langle t\rangle$ for any $t\in \mathfrak{m}-\mathfrak{m^2}$ Now I want to show that $R$ is a discrete valuation ring and I want to do this by explicitly constructing a discrete valuation function. To do this I need to prove that every element $x\in R-\{0\}$ can be written in the form $ut^n$ with $u$ unit in $R$. In the link provided above this inference is treated as an immediate inference in need of no clarification. But I don't know how to prove it.

$R$ is a local ring and $\mathfrak{m}$ is its maximal ideal, so every element of $R \setminus \mathfrak{m}$ is a unit. Hence, for any element $u$ in the complement of $\mathfrak{m}$, just take $n = 0$.
Now, consider nonzero $x \in \mathfrak{m} = \langle t \rangle$. Write $x = x_{1}t$ for some $x_{1} \in R$. If $x_{1} \notin \mathfrak{m}$, then we're done by the above. Otherwise, write $x_{1} = x_{2}t$ for some $x_{2} \in R$. Repeating this process, we continue until either we write $x = x_{n}t^{n}$ for some $x_{n} \notin \mathfrak{m}$, or we construct a sequence $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots$ such that $x_{i} = x_{i+1}t$.
We now show that the latter case cannot happen. Indeed, if it did, then we would have an ascending chain
$$\langle x_{1} \rangle \subset \langle x_{2} \rangle \subset \cdots$$
which must terminate because $R$ is Noetherian, and so we must have $\langle x_{k} \rangle = \langle x_{k+1} \rangle$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. By hypothesis, $x_{k} = x_{k+1}t$, so if $x_{k+1} = rx_{k}$ for some $r \in R$, then we have $x_{k} = rtx_{k}$. We deduce $(1-rt)x_{k} = 0$, but $rt \in \mathfrak{m}$, so $1-rt$ is a unit. This gives a contradiction, since then $x_{k}$ must be $0$, which it cannot be if $x$ is nonzero.

Thank you for the answer. I have a follow-up question here.
